# Usage of sliders for non-commercial use

Tags: website-design, interaction-design, design-patterns, design

So I know that sliders are bad and there's a thing called banner blindness and read couple of studies saying that people don't interact with them at all. However I'm working on an "About Us" page where the client would like to implement the idea of having a slider with qualities of the company. I proposed an idea to go with a simple animation instead like in this [example](https://www.castoretpollux.com/). My question is which one is better for non-commercial use on a site without ads, banner or animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "About Us" page on a website is a perfect section of a website to incorporate the views and goals of a company with the style of the page. I believe there is no 'best' with this but there is 'best/most suited'. I took a peek at your question history and I believe you have done your research regarding the goal(s) of the website.

#### What is the best here?

It has been proven that sliders do not work in most situations, it is mostly there to look pretty.

I believe your suggestion is a nice in-between, your boss wants to show multiple slides (I think it is because it 'looks nice' and fancy) and your suggestion looks nice as well.

My personal preference, without knowing more about the website will be an animation (for instance like the one you linked), mainly because in general they grab more [attention](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/animation-usability/) then a static image/banner. Secondly they are important in the current webdesign trends (background animations / micro interactions etc.).

Comment: Yes I also incorporated those in my wireframes but those will go below that and will be with more detailed description. i was thinking putting the animation on top of the page with major keywords and later taking those and explaining them below in "timeline-ish" infographic. And yeah, I've done a little bit of digging here and there but it was mostly for our dashboard :D. Exactly that, but I explained him the thing with banner blindness and how is it bad for SEO, stuff like that so he took it. Thanks a lot for the reply! I needed to verify my design :)

Comment: Regarding some inspiration, Moz used to have a 'timeline about' page. Sadly they changed it but it looked great. [Here](https://undullify.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/about-page-inspiration-2-moz.jpg) is an image how it looked like.

Answer (score -3):

In a private, non-commercial environment, bereft of you being required to take responsibility for the user experience, and wherein the client has a specific desire/demand, the client is right. Every.Single.Time!

Bill him more hours if he changes his mind later.

Comment: First off I don't really think that's a good approach as it's also our part of job to teach the higher ups about UX. Secondly I didn't say he said no to my proposition I just asked which one of those is better and how is it with banner blindness in non e-commerce use.

Comment: good luck with that.